# Ligatures and hyphenations: the effect of empty brace groups {}

Tags: tex-core, hyphenation, ligatures

For the following example,

```
\hsize =2in

shelf{}ful shelf{}ful shelf{}ful
rot{}ten rot{}ten
shelf{}ful shelf{}ful shelf{}ful

shelf{}ful shelf{}ful
rot{}ten rot{}ten
shelf{}ful shelf{}ful

\bye
```

The result is as followings:

[image]

My questions is: in the first paragraph, why the first `shelfful` is without ligature, but the other `shelfful` are with ligatures?

Comment: TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word of a paragraph.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What does that mean? A little more info would be welcome.

Comment: @Manuel: It means what it says: The braces are obviously lost when TeX tries to find hyphenation points which it doesn't do on the first work of a paragraph.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Mmm… I don't get it. There are two paragraphs, and *only in the first one* all but the first `{}` seem to do nothing, since the `ff` are ligatured.

Comment: @Manuel: the second paragraph has no hyphenation at all. TeX was able to set it without having to find hyphenation points.

Comment: The TeXBook (TeX3 version, not TeX2 edition)  explicitly warns against using `{}` to break ligatures for precisely this reason, the `{}` is lost if the word is reconstituted after a hyphenation trial.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Understood (better with the comment of David :P).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The TeXBook has this exercise:

> **exercise** Sometimes you run into a rare word like 'shelfful' that
>   looks better as `shelf{}ful` without the `ff` ligature. How can you
>   fool TeX into thinking that there aren't two consecutive f's in such
>   a word?
>
> **answer** `{shelf}ful` or `shelf{}ful`, etc.; or even
>   `shelf\/ful`, which yields a shelf/ful instead of a
>   shelf{\kern0pt}ful. In fact, the latter idea---to insert an italic
>   correction---is preferable because TeX will ^reinsert the ff
>   ligature by itself after hyphenating `shelf{}ful`. Appendix H
>   points out that ligatures are put into a hyphenated word that contains
>   no explicit kerns, and an italic correction is an explicit
>   kern.)  But the italic correction may be too much (especially in an
>   italic font); `shelf{\kern0pt}ful` is often best.

Note here that "after hyphenating" should be read as "after *trying* to hyphenate"
If TeX attempts to hyphenate a word it essentially splits it up at the possible
break points to add discretionary hyphens. If then hyphenation is not used at that point the word is reconstituted without those hyphenation points, but the original `{}` information is lost by then and ligatures will be formed in the reconstituted word.

TeX (not luatex) never attempts to hyphenate the first word of a paragraph (essentially a bug that was classified as a feature to keep TeX stable) and also it does not attempt to hyphenate any words in a paragraph if it can break the paragraph into lines and keep within `\pretolerance` badness. So whether `f{}f` actually breaks an ff ligature is rather variable depending on the whole paragraph, not just the word where `{}` is used.

Comment: Even more important not to use `{}` when LuaTeX is involved, as it deliberately doesn't follow the same approach as 'classical' TeX (but there are Lua-based ways to suppress ligatures in defined words).

Comment: Actually the question does come from my reading of this exercise of the TeXbook. I think `after hyphenating shelf{}ful` is misleading for first learners since it is the same when TeX hyphenating other words. Could you update your answer with more details about your comment below the original question? That would benifit other people.

Comment: @Z.H. better?..

Comment: @JosephWright Could you please elaborate on the _Lua-based ways to suppress ligatures in defined words?_ Do you have anything else in mind than the _selnolig_ package?

Comment: @StephanHennig - Is there something about the `selnolig` package you'd like to see changed?

Comment: @Mico Not at all.  I'm interested in the range of existing solutions.  I'll give some background to my question if I find some more time.  In the meantime, JosephWright, could you please clarify what you were referring to?

Comment: @StephanHennig - Thanks. I'm always eager to find out if people can come up with better methods than those currently used in the `selnolig` package. :-)