# What are the incompatibilities of pdftex, xetex and luatex?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, tex-core

<sup>[Please correct me if my statements are wrong]</sup>

**TL;DR:** `pdftex`, `xetex` and `luatex` exhibit different behaviour. What are these differences and why are they present.

---

I know of three engines, which implement TeX and support native PDF output: `pdftex`, `xetex` and `luatex`. Unfortunately they are not completely compatible.

`pdftex` is an ɛ-TeX engine, which is downward compatible to Knuth-TeX, i.e. there will be not difference in the typeset output of `pdftex` and `tex` (breakpoints, pagebreaks, ligatures, dimensions, etc. are *exactly* the same).

## Example of an Incompatibility

This is not true for `xetex` and `luatex`. I just know of one obvious incompatibility which I will support by a MWE in a moment. To prevent a ligature, Knuth suggest several alternatives in the TeXbook in exercise 5.1

> `{shelf}ful` or `shelf{}ful`, etc.; or even `shelf\/ful`, which yields a shelfful (w/ ligature) instead of a shelfful (w/o ligature). In fact, the latter idea—to insert an italic correction—is preferable because TeX will reinsert the ff ligature by itself after hyphenating `shelf{}ful`. (Appendix H points out that ligatures are put into a hyphenated word that contains no “explicit kerns,” and an italic correction is an explicit kern.) But the italic correction may be too much (especially in an italic font); `shelf{\kern0pt}ful` is often best.

Thus having the following plainTeX document should always result in the ff ligature being disabled

```
shelf{}ful
\bye
```

### pdftex

The output of `tex` and `pdftex` is as expected

[image]

### luatex

But for `luatex` I obtain

[image]

### xetex

For `xetex` I get the same as for `pdftex`

[image]

but as soon as I load an OpenType font as in

```
\font\test="CMU Serif" \test
shelf{}ful
\bye
```

the ligature reappears

[image]

## Another example (which turned out to be a bug)

The code

```
${}\limits$
\bye
```

will typeset without any complaint under `luatex` whereas it will throw the error

```
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.
```

with `pdftex` or `xetex`.

This example will also throw the appropriate error for `luatex`versions > beta-0.79.1.

## Summary

In the end my question boils down to several points:

- What are the incompatibilities of `xetex` and `luatex` with `pdftex`?
- Why did the designers choose to break compatibility with Knuth?
- Can I restore compatibility by making specific design choices (i.e. breaking ligatures with `\kern0pt` instead of `{}`)?

---

**N.B.:** Please don't get too caught up by the example. I'm not asking for a solution to this specific problem. If you are searching for a solution to it, visit those links

- [Difference between {} and \/ for breaking ligatures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106487/difference-between-and-for-breaking-ligatures)
- [Ligatures and hyphenations: the effect of empty brace groups {}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209449/ligatures-and-hyphenations-the-effect-of-empty-brace-groups)

---

## List of known incompatibilities

Here I collect links to questions/answers which point out some of the incompatibilities.  It is intended for users contemplating to switch engines, but want to known what to watch out for.

- [Why is the fraction off the math axis in XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549)
- [LuaLatex and large braces with MathTime Professional 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232109)

Comment: There's a big difference between the XeTeX and LuaTeX cases. XeTeX should give the same output as pdfTeX for input that would be valid for Knuth's TeX (_i.e._ any variations here are bugs or with pdfTeX places where XeTeX doesn't have the primitives), whereas LuaTeX quite deliberately alters some areas.

Comment: The LuaTeX developers implemented a completely new mechanism for ligatures; XeTeX, when using OTF or TTF fonts, had to change the way boxes are built, which has the consequence that the ligature `ff` is reconstructed, if `f{}f` is input: the different font technology requires different methods.

Comment: `shelf{}ful` does *not* suppress the ligature with pdftex in all cases. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209449/ligatures-and-hyphenations-the-effect-of-empty-brace-groups and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106487/difference-between-and-for-breaking-ligatures

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is true (as also explained in the excerpt from the TeXbook I cited), but for this simple MWE the ligature should *always* be broken. Also it's just an example for an incompatibility I am aware of.

Comment: Sure it is an incompatibility. But one that is of no practical interest as you shouldn't break up ligatures like this. It only works with pdftex in some cases as the engine avoids to lookup hyphenations in the first pass - probably to save some time - and so is only a side-effect.

Comment: I love that adding the slash-space after non-sentence ending periods is automatic: `i.e.\ ` :-) I do the same thing routinely here!

Comment: @darthbith Old habits die hard :)

Comment: To respond to the specific issue about ligatures, I just want to point users to the new `selnolig` package which aims to improve the default ligature selection.

Comment: @HenriMenke A “list of primitives” wouldn't be sufficient; there are several places where, due to font technology and programming choices, the output of XeTeX and LuaTeX can be different. And it's not easy to precisely find *where* the output can be different.

Comment: Echoing egreg's view, the differences between pdf(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX can *not* be summarized adequately by listing and comparing the set of "primitive" commands the two engines understand. For instance, the approaches to kerning, ligaturing, hyphenation, and many other aspects of building a paragraph are quite different between the two engines.

Comment: New example is almost certainly a bug in LuaTeX: report it. There are lots of things in LuaTeX that are complete rewrites from TeX90, and it's not surprising that not all of them are not currently 100% correct.

Comment: Related question: [pdftex - Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642), [pdftex - Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984), [xetex - Frequently loaded packages: Differences between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87155)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

pdfTeX is intended to offer complete compatibility with Knuth's TeX, and thus if the e-TeX extensions are not enabled should act in the same way.

XeTeX is based on the e-TeX code and does not set out to break any compatibility with Knuth's TeX unless it is absolutely necessary (*i.e.* there is no reimplementation of algorithms unless this relates to adding new features). However, there are places that differences occur. As noted in the question, XeTeX can load system fonts. When this is done, a new approach to placing boxes on the page is used. Possibly only those with deep involvement in that code can comment on whether it was absolutely necessary not to support the `{}` approach to breaking ligatures, but [as noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222286/what-are-the-incompatibilities-of-pdftex-xetex-and-luatex#comment521325_222286) that [doesn't always work anyway](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209449/ligatures-and-hyphenations-the-effect-of-empty-brace-groups). Changes also occur where the classical TeX syntax is extended. For example, allowing more than two `^` is done to allow access to the full Unicode range. However, as shown in http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Encodings_and_Regimes that leads to code which does different things in 8-bit and Unicode TeX engines:

```
\def\"{0}\expandafter\def\csname^^^^^00022\endcsname{1}
\ifnum\"=0 \message{tex82}\else\message{newstuff}\fi
```

LuaTeX is a very different case. The designers have decided to revisit a number of Knuth's decisions: the LuaTeX manual covers the detail (there is quite a bit). For example, the fact that `{}` does not inhibit a ligature is deliberate and relates to how LuaTeX process the input and represents it in internal data structures.  LuaTeX treats hyphenation as a property of *language* not of *font*. As such, LuaTeX can hyphenate words using different fonts if the language does not change. As a result, hyphenation is governed by per-language primitives. (LuaTeX can also hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, which Knuth's TeX does not do and which is nowadays a 'feature'.) LuaTeX also has the same issues as XeTeX in terms of extending primitives for Unicode working: see the demo above for example.

Worth noting is that as LuaTeX supports callbacks functionality unchanged by the engine may be altered by Lua code. An obvious example is the `\font` primitive. This is not extended by the engine, but is by a Lua-based font loader: plain and LaTeX users share the same code here while ConTeXt has its own (related) loader.

For both XeTeX and LuaTeX it is worth noting that the extension of math mode to allow a  number of additional Unicode math parameters to be used (all prefixed `\Umath...`)  means that math mode spacing may change if these additional data points are available, principally when using a Unicode math font.

The bottom line from all of this is that if you have an 8-bit document written for pdfTeX, e-TeX or indeed TeX90 you should be able to use pdfTeX to process it unchanged. XeTeX will give the same result with almost all files of the same form *assuming* they don't contain any engine tests or similar, and assuming that the contain no driver-specific code (XeTeX uses the xdvipdfmx driver in all cases, pdfTeX may use dvips, dvipdfmx or direct PDF output). LuaTeX may change the behaviour of such documents, including but not limited to hyphenation, line breaking, ligature formation and so on.

---

Looking at the question purely in terms of primitives, we have to decide if we are comparing XeTeX and LuaTeX with TeX90, e-TeX or pdfTeX1.40. The question seems to be focussed on 'current' engines, so I will take pdfTeX 1.40 as the 'reference (it incorporates the e-TeX modifications to TeX90 plus a range of additional primitives). As noted in the part above, some behaviours are changes in XeTeX and LuaTeX. I'll note where possible any TeX90/e-TeX/pdfTeX variations which seem important in this context.  Quite a bit of this information is available in the LuaTeX manual.

As XeTeX and LuaTeX allow Unicode input, and primitives which are followed by the `<number>` of a character are affected by the change:

- `\char`
- `\lccode`
- `\uccode`
- `\catcode`
- `\sfcode`
- `\efcode` (LuaTeX-only: see below)
- `\lpcode`
- `\rpcode`
- `\chardef`

These all accept the full Unicode range (up to 0x10FFFF) with the newer engines: pdfTeX like e-TeX and TeX90 allows only the 8-bit range (maximum 0xFF).

LuaTeX extends the range of registers allowed beyond that of e-TeX. Thus while pdfTeX and XeTeX allow up to 32767 box, count, dimen, muskip, marks and toks registers, LuaTeX allows a 16-bit range (max is 65535). This affects the primitives

- `\count`
- `\dimen`
- `\skip`
- `\muskip`
- `\marks`
- `\toks`
- `\countdef`
- `\dimendef`
- `\skipdef`
- `\muskipdef`
- `\toksdef`
- `\box`
- `\unhbox`
- `\unvbox`
- `\copy`
- `\unhcopy`
- `\unvcopy`
- `\wd`
- `\ht`
- `\dp`
- `\setbox`
- `\vsplit`

The `\font` primitive is extended by XeTeX to allow loading of system fonts with the syntax

```
\font⟨name⟩="⟨font identifier⟩⟨font options⟩:⟨font features⟩" ⟨TeX font options⟩
```

where the `⟨font identifier⟩` may be given in square brackets for a file name or without with a 'friendly' (system) name. This is not the case in LuaTeX: as noted above, LuaTeX is normally used with a Lua-based font loader which modifies the primitive *via* a callback.

LuaTeX allows file names to be given in braces as primitive sytnax, for example

```
\input{file name}
```

This affects the primitives

- `\font` (note: this is purely to do with the file name of the font)
- `\input`
- `\openin`
- `\openout`

pdfTeX adds a number of primitives to e-TeX, some related to PDF creation, some for microtypography and some general utilities. As XeTeX is based directly on e-TeX and not on pdfTeX, it only features some of these where they have been ported across. Some of the primitive are also renamed as they are no PDF-related. Thus XeTeX includes the following concepts introduced by pdfTeX:

- `\lpcode`
- `\rpcode`
- `\pdfpageheight`
- `\pdfpagewidth`
- `\pdfsavepos`
- `\pdflastxpos`
- `\pdflastypos`
- `\ifincsname`
- `\ifprimitive` (`\ifpdfprimitive` in pdfTeX)
- `\primitive` (`\pdfprimitive` in pdfTeX)
- `\strcmp` (`\pdfstrcmp` in pdfTeX`)
- `\shellescape` (`\pdfshellescape` in pdfTeX)
- `\normaldeviate` (TL'19 onward, `\pdfnormaldeviate` in pdfTeX)
- `\uniformdeviate` (TL'19 onward, `\pdfuniformdeviate` in pdfTeX)
- `\randomseed` (TL'19 onward, `\pdfrandomseed` in pdfTeX)
- `\setrandomseed` (TL'19 onward, `\pdfsetrandomseed` in pdfTeX)
- `\elapsedtime` (TL'19 onward, `\pdfelapsedtime` in pdfTeX)
- `\resettimer` (TL'19 onward, `\pdfresettimer` in pdfTeX)
- `\filedump` (TL'19 onward, `\pdffiledump` in pdfTeX)
- `\filemoddate` (TL'19 onward, `\pdffilemoddate` in pdfTeX)
- `\filesize` (TL'19 onward, `\pdffilesize` in pdfTeX)
- `\mdfivesum` (TL'19 onward, `\pdfmdfivesum` in pdfTeX)

but not for example `\efcode` (as noted above), `\pdfliteral` or many others.

LuaTeX is based on pdfTeX and retains some of the primitives introduced there, renames some to remove 'pdf' and drops others. As well as primitives marked as experimental or deprecated in pdfTeX 1.40, LuaTeX also removes the primitives:

- `\pdfelapsedtime`
- `\pdfescapehex`
- `\pdfescapename`
- `\pdfescapestring`
- `\pdffiledump`
- `\pdffilemoddate`
- `\pdffilesize`
- `\pdflastmatch`
- `\pdfmatch`
- `\pdfmdfivesum`
- `\pdfresettimer`
- `\pdfshellescape`
- `\pdfstrcmp`
- `\pdfunescapehex`

and provides

- `\primitive`
- `\ifprimitive`
- `\ifabsnum`
- `\ifabsdim`

without 'pdf' in the name. It also moves all of the 'back end' concepts (to do with producing PDF output) to three new primitives which implement the functionality of the various PDF-related `\pdf...` primitives from pdfTeX.

Currently, XeTeX and pdfTeX use the 'TeX--XeT' model for right-to-left typesetting while LuaTeX uses one derived from Omega/Aleph. As such, it does not feature the primitives

- `\TeXXeTstate`
- `\beginR`
- `\beginL`
- `\endR`
- `\endL`

(Note that there has been suggestion that XeTeX may at some stage move from TeX--XeT to the Omega model.)

LuaTeX also alters the behaviour of `\endlinechar` and `\newlinechar`: the maximum value is 127 while setting any value below zero stores -1.

Both XeTeX and LuaTeX *add* new primitives to TeX and the behaviour of these of course requires the appropriate engine. Note in particular that new primitives for Unicode math handling (`\Umath...`) are available in both engines. The also both feature `\suppressfontnotfounderror`.

Comment: A lot of the primitive information comes from the LuaTeX and XeTeX manuals. I've not included anything that seems to be erroneous behaviour (perhaps the point about LuaTeX and negative `\endlinechar`/`\newlinechar` will change: unclear if this is deliberate).

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you again for improving your already *extensive* answer. I hope the +100 can make up for the effort you had to put in it.

Comment: +10 if I could: As someone who has worked with LuaTeX for some time, I believe there is nothing substantial to add to this great answer (actually, I do not know of anything not covered in this answer) regarding LuaTeX. I can't comment on XeTeX.

Comment: Another difference is that they all use different [graphics drivers](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/projects/latexfmxdef/).  Sometimes the XeTeX driver clips included graphics more closely than the PDFTeX or LuaTeX ([example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223904/how-do-i-make-a-circle-of-fermions-in-feynmp-a-self-energy-photon)).  Is it worth expanding the answer to cover these differences?

Comment: @Thruston That's a rather complex area: you can happily use pdfTeX with `dvipdfmx` and get the same result as XeTeX. The abilities of a driver are not necessarily tied to the engine.

Answer (score 1):

In LuaTeX, several `\pdf...` primitives of pdfTeX are removed or renamed, as mentioned in [Joseph Wright's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222300/250119).

As a result, some packages does not work in LuaLaTeX, for example, [`xypic` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xypic) ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328604/250119)) or [`gridset` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427533/250119) (old version only, has been fixed).

There are a few solutions that could be used to fix them:

- [`pdftexcmds` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdftexcmds) defines some commands such as `\pdf@elapsedtime` (note the change in name, `@` added) that works in both pdfTeX and LuaTeX. --- [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32360/250119).

  This option is only useful if you are a package developer, and want to write code that is compatible with both pdfTeX and LuaTeX.
- [`luatex85` compatibility package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luatex85) can be used to define commands such as `\pdfsavepos` etc. in LuaTeX --- [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370644/250119).

  I'm not sure if there's any disadvantage of using a compatibility package in newly-written packages --- the alternative is to check manually in your package code whether pdfTeX/XeTeX or LuaTeX is used, and use the corresponding primitive.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about XeTeX, but LuaTeX offers the possibility of doing some things using Lua programs, without the need for shell escape. For example, it is possible to examine the content of arbitrary files (not just TeX) on a per-byte basis, and dynamically change what TeX does based on the results.

A lot of this is already incorporated into various packages nowadays (it has been a long time since the original question). It is possible to invoke Lua within a package *.sty file, but extended code is generally placed in a separate *.lua file. If your browse through the various TeX packages, you will see such code here and there. For example, it is possible (and already implemented) to change some internal properties of a font, when the font is used by TeX. It is possible to learn some properties of an image file, without the need to invoke a separate graphics program.

As already noted, there was a deliberate decision to do some things differently than the original TeX. At this time, LuaTeX is well-developed.

Comment: To be fair "compatibility" usually means "backwards compatibility" (pdftex being "incompatible" with luatex doesn't really mean in this sense since these counts as new features), but this may also be worth mentioning.

Comment: @user202729 Good point. But I loike to think "forwards." :)