# How do I make a circle of fermions in feynmp? (a self-energy photon)

Tags: feynmf, feynmp-auto

I'm trying to draw a photon turning into a circle formed by one fermions going one way and the other going the other way, but they both go up. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb,aps,12pt,eqsecnum]{revtex4}  
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}  
\linespread{1}  
\usepackage[breaklinks, colorlinks, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}  
\usepackage{slashed}  
\usepackage{simplewick}  
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  
\usepackage{textcomp}  
\usepackage{gensymb}  

\begin{fmffile}{rad4}  
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(80,120)  
        \fmftop{t1,t2}  
        \fmfbottom{b1,b2}  
        \fmf{fermion}{b1,v1,t1}  
        \fmf{fermion}{b2,v4,t2}  
        \fmffreeze  
        \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}  
        \fmf{phantom}{v2,v3}  
        \fmf{photon}{v3,v4}  
        \fmffreeze  
        \fmf{fermion,left,tension=0}{v2,v3}  
        \fmf{fermion,right,tension=0}{v3,v2}  
    \end{fmfgraph*}  
\end{fmffile}
```

[image: fermion circle]

This is what I'm currently getting, any ideas?
(i.e. I would like one of the fermions in the middle to go down and form a circle)
Thanks for the edit egreg!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that last fermion to

```
\fmf{fermion,left,tension=0}{v3,v2}
```

Since it's going backwards from `v3` to `v2` it needs to bend left not right.
Then you get:

[image]

Here's my complete, minimal compilable version of your picture:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}  
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{rad4}  
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(80,120)  
        \fmftop{t1,t2}  
        \fmfbottom{b1,b2}  
        \fmf{fermion}{b1,v1,t1}  
        \fmf{fermion}{b2,v4,t2}  
        \fmffreeze  
        \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}  
        \fmf{phantom}{v2,v3}  
        \fmf{photon}{v3,v4}  
        \fmffreeze  
        \fmf{fermion,left,tension=0}{v2,v3}  
        \fmf{fermion,left,tension=0}{v3,v2}  
    \end{fmfgraph*}  
\end{fmffile}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to generate the same diagram, but then with a dashed line coming out of the loop in the middle. It should go to the top. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I tried   \begin{fmfgraph*}(75,50)
   \fmfleft{i1,o1}
   \fmfright{i2,o2}
   \fmftop{t1}
   \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
   \fmf{fermion}{i2,v5,o2}
         \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}  
         \fmf{phantom}{v2,v4}  
         \fmf{photon}{v4,v5}  
   \fmf{fermion,left,tension=0}{v2,v3} 
   \fmf{fermion,left,tension=0}{v3,v4} 
   \fmf{fermion,left,tension=0}{v4,v2} 
   \fmf{dashes}{v3,t1}
  \end{fmfgraph*}      But it looks horrible.

Comment: @Funzies - the usual thing to do here is to ask a new question as a new question not just as a comment.

Comment: @Funzies as I didn't see you posting a separate question about this, I'll suggest solution here. You should first put an `\fmffreeze` command after the diagram in this answer, and after that add your `t1` and `v3` vertices. And with `\fmfforce` you can set their position as you like. See for example the TeX code of [this diagram](http://bartosik.pp.ua/feynman_diagrams/ttbar_gg_s_isr_g) with a gluon line drawn after `\fmffreeze`.