# mtpro2 and lualatex

Tags: luatex, mtpro

I'm trying to reproduce this formula from `mtpro2`'s list of fonts (https://www.pctex.com/files/managed/5/52/MTP2flyerFontList.pdf).

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\LEFTRIGHT(){
    1
    +
    \SQRT{%
        1
        +
        \LEFTRIGHT\lbrace\rbrace{
            \hspace{-0.3em}
            \begin{array}{c}
            \displaystyle\XL\sum\limits_{ i = 1 }^N
            \LEFTRIGHT(.{
                \int_a^b f_i (x) \, dx
                +
                \xl\sum_{ j,k }
                \XL\int_a^b
                \frac{
                        \sum\limits_{ l = 1 }^n
                            g_{jl}(x) + h_{jl}(x)
                    }{
                        \sum\limits_{ l = 1 }^n
                            g_{kl}(x) + h_{il}(x)
                }
                \,
                dx
            }
            \\
            \phantom{AAAAAAAAA}
            +
            \LEFTRIGHT.){
                \SQRT{%
                    \frac{
                            i
                            +
                            \displaystyle\sum\limits_{\alpha}
                            \widetildedown{2pt}{\widetilde{
                                a_{\alpha 1}
                                +
                                a_{\alpha 2}
                                +
                                \cdots
                                +
                                a_{\alpha n}
                            }}
                    }{
                            \undercbrace{
                                \widehatdown{2pt}{\widehat{
                                    A_1
                                    +
                                    A_2
                                    +
                                    A_3
                                    +
                                    A_4
                                    +
                                    \cdots
                                }}
                            }_{\text{for all } A_i > \pi/2}
                    }
                }
            }^{ \sqrt{ \alpha } + \sqrt{ \vphantom{\beta^2} \beta } }
        \end{array}
        }^{\hspace{-0.5em}\alpha + \beta}
    }
\hspace{1em}
}^{\hspace{-1.5em}\alpha^2 + \beta^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

When compiled with `pdflatex`, the result is more or less identical. But when compiled with `lualatex`, certainly some features of `mtpro2` do work: there are large operator symbols, wide tildes and hats, the font itself seems right. Even the horizontal brace is right! However, the radicals and vertical delimiters seem to be from Latin Modern.

Comment: Curious about this one. I tried applying the solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309746/301662) but to no avail: for me, the parentheses and curly brackets [refuse to enlarge](https://i.ibb.co/M9YPdGp/4.png) all the way.