# LuaLaTeX and xypic

Tags: luatex, xy-pic

The newest versions of the package `xy-pic` does not work properly with LuaLaTeX, version 0.95.0. Consider the following simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix {
  A\ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
  C\ar[r] & D
}
\]

\end{document}
```

The first error message, which appears while compiling this with `lualatex` is

```
Package xypdf Error: pdfTeX version 1.40.0 or higher is needed for the xypdf
```

It’s possible to avoid this error message by adding the following line at the beginning of `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xypic/xypdf.tex`

```
\input /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/context/luatex/luatex-pdf.tex
```

However, even then LuaLaTeX produces errors:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
\line@ ->\setboxz@h {\xP@setsolidpat \xP@stroke 
                                                {0 0 m \xP@coor {\cosDirecti... 
l.13 }
```

and the result looks like this:

[image: The attempt of plotting a commutative diagram with LuaLaTeX]

Comment: I'd also recommned having a look at switching to `tikz-cd`, IMO it ends up looking better and is more flexible.

Comment: Just do `\input{luatex-pdf}` immediately after the `\documentclass` line. And *don't* modify distributed files.

Answer (score 6):

Until `xypic` is updated, you can use the `luatex85` compatibility package:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
% no not with luatex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix {
  A\ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
  C\ar[r] & D
}
\]

\end{document}
```

with log:

```
 *File List*
luatex85.sty    2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 Experimental document command parser
luaotfload.sty    2016/06/16 v2.7 OpenType layout system
fontspec-luatex.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu2enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu2lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu2lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2016/08/17 v0.01g Graphics/Color for luaTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
fontspec.cfg
      xy.sty    2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but this doesn’t work either; the errors are the same.

Comment: @FKranhold worked for me without error, let me do an update to see if xypic changed recently...

Comment: Oh, sorry: I commented out a line in `xypdf.tex` wrongly.

Comment: @FKranhold :-) anyway I updated with the output and the `\listfiles` output showing file versions used.

Comment: work around still needed (Fedora)

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider the use of `tikz-cd`, which runs your example using LuaLaTeX virtually without change:

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  A\ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
  C\ar[r] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Example run from tikz-cd]