# \pdfmapfile and \luatexttextdir commands not accepted anymore by luatex

Tags: luatex, arabic

My LuaTeX 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) do not recognize command `\pdfmapfile` anymore, how can I load information on fonts?

The `\luatexttextdir TRT` is not recognized either, how can I request a different text direction?

I found no trace of the latter in the LuaTeX documentation (although by dad package developed a few years ago was heavily relying on it) and for the former it is only said that `pdf.mapfile` is replacing it, does this mean that I have to switch to Lua to call a map file?

Comment: luatex 0.85 dropped most of the `\pdf...` commands replacing them by combinations with (in this case) `\pdfextension mapfile`  the luatex85 package defines the old names but betetr long term is to update not to need it. the other is a latex change, once support fro lualatex was brought in to the core we no longer prefixed luatex primitives with `luatex`  so `\textdir` is available under the name that it is documented as, rather than `\luatextextdir` as in early releases.

Comment: Related question: [What are the incompatibilities of pdftex, xetex and luatex? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222286/what-are-the-incompatibilities-of-pdftex-xetex-and-luatex)

Answer (score 3):

For the `\pdfmapfile` use the luatex85 package, and `\textdir` instead of `\luatextextdir`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatex85}

\pdfmapfile{=fontawesome.map}
\begin{document}
blbl

\textdir TRT abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I would like my dad package to be stable in the long term, is it pertinent to use a "compatibility" package?

Comment: @yannis It's mentioned in the comment that the primitive syntax supported by LuaTeX is `\pdfextension mapfile`.