# TeX Gyre Termes' ligatures work in LuaLaTeX, but fail in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, ligatures

I recently installed TeX Gyre Termes, and I noticed that ligatures were present when I compiled with LuaLaTeX, but not with XeLaTeX:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{TeXGyreTermes} % no spaces in name

\begin{document}

fi ff fl ffi

\end{document}
```

XeLaTeX: [image: fi ff fl ffi]

LuaLaTeX: [image: ligatures properly rendered]

The same problem arises with small caps- in LuaLaTeX, all works well, but upon switching to XeLaTeX, small caps disappear, and XeLaTeX warns me that it must substitute with normal TeX Gyre Termes instead of small caps. I suspect that the issue is related to my installation of TeX Gyre Termes, as ligatures are present when other fonts are used. However, I have tried re-installing TeX Gyre Termes multiple times, but this issue persists.

Therefore, my question is: because I am unable to use a functional copy of TeX Gyre Termes, and because XeLaTeX compiles faster than LuaLaTeX, *what can I do to ensure that ligatures appear when I compile with XeLaTeX?*

(I do not want to switch out TeX Gyre Termes with another Times-like font, as I prefer its italic best. However, I do not care whether the OpenType version of the font is used or not.)

This question seems related: 
[What are the incompatibilities of pdftex, xetex and luatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222286/what-are-the-incompatibilities-of-pdftex-xetex-and-luatex)
However, it does not discuss the reason behind this difference, and what may be done about it.

Comment: It is my understanding that XeLaTeX cannot load Open Type fonts by font name, from the TeX distribution folder. It can only load them by file name. Could it be that the fonts are being loaded from your operating system instead? LuaaTeX does not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I doubt those images are made from that input `ff` making a `fl` ligature? :-) for me it works and gives ligatures in xelatex texlive 2017 with `\setromanfont{TeX Gyre Termes}`  or  `\setromanfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}`  The version with the  font name but spaces removed fails to find the file at all.

Comment: @RobtAll texlive includes a configuration file for fontconfig so that font files in texlive can be found by font name.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle haha, I completely missed that. :) However, the OTF version that I have is without spaces, and with spaces, TeX cannot find the font. I don't know how I wound up with a version of TeX Gyre Termes that differs from that of everybody else- I got it from GUST's website- but my question concerns what to do *given* that I have a version of TeX Gyre Termes that differs from others and that I so far cannot correct.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use? Please advise.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Before I commented, I tried the OP's MWE (with Tex Gyre installed) but it couldn't find the fonts in XeLaTeX. I see that it has something to do with how the font name is written. Since I never use XeLaTeX except for trying other people's MWEs, I missed that.

Comment: @RobtAll - If your TeX distribution is of relatively recent vintage, `\setromanfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` should work under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I am using MikTeX, but using the same OTF file with ShareLaTeX results in the same error. Do note that the actual name of the font according to Windows is `TeXGyreTermes`; that is to say, if I opened Microsoft Office, then the font name would still appear as `TeXGyreTermes` and would **not** appear as `Tex Gyre Termes`.

Comment: if you have installed the font yourself where have you put it (easiest is usually to install it in the windows font directory) if it is there then it should work try first with the `\setromanfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}` form

Comment: With `tex-gyre` installed via MikTeX's Package Manager (Admin) the MWE works for me if I use `\setromanfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` with spaces. If I compile the MWE without spaces the ligatures are only shown with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle setting the font as `texgyretermes-regular.otf` seems to do the trick for XeLaTeX, although like the image in my original post, the ffi ligature still does not appear (instead an ff ligature is followed by a letter i). At any rate, I am satisfied with the results of what you suggested in your comment; if you convert it into an answer, I may accept it (depending on whether Ulrike changes his answer). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xelatex and lualatex use different methods to search for fonts. xelatex uses fontconfig, lualatex (or more precisely the package luaotfload used to load fonts) has its own database.

This means that sometimes the one engine finds a font but not the other depending e.g. on spaces or uppercaseing(lualatex don't care, while xelatex is rather picky).

My guess is that one your system xelatex is finding a type1 font when you use the name without spaces. You could add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` and check the log-file, to confirm this guess.

Comment: After using `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1`, I find many messages that resemble `LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font 'operators' in version 'normal' TU/TeXGyreTermes(0)/m/n --> TU/TeXGyreTermes(0)/m/n on input line 147.`I also loaded Arial and Courier New, which also show up as TU, so I do not believe that it shows up as a T1 font.

Comment: @RobertZhang `T1` in latex refers to a font _encoding_ (of 256 characters per font) as opposed to `OT1` (127 characters) or `TU` (Unicode). That is unrelated to "Type 1" which is a PostScript font fomat which in xetex is best avoided if you have a opentype version of the font.

Comment: @RobertZhang you can check the font type used in the final pdf using acrobat font menu or the pdffonts commandline utility

Comment: You need to find the names of the font files in the log. Do they end with otf or pfb?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer in fact, they do end with pfb. The log file shows messages like `Requested font "TeXGyreTermes/OT" at 12.0pt
 -> C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qtmr.pfb`

Comment: Pfb fonts are type1 fonts and this is the wrong font format, it should be otf or ttf.