# \savepos=\savepos in lualatex. Why?

Tags: luatex, grid-typesetting, pdfsavepos

I use LuaLaTeX. Today I decided to try the `gridset` package. To my surprise, `\usepackage{gridset}` produced an error, telling me that the `\savepos` command was already defined.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% will be undefined in pdflatex, defines as itself in lualatex: 
\show\savepos
\begin{document}
yada yada
\end{document}
```

It seems that LuaLaTeX defines `\savepos=\savepos`. That's odd.

If I first un-define `\savepos` then I can load `gridset` in LuaLaTeX, and it appears to work:

```
\let\savepos\relax
\usepackage{gridset}
% Then I can use \savepos in the document body.
```

Is this an "oops," or is there a reason for that behavior in LuaLaTex?

EDIT: In response to ShreevatsaR's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
% compile with lualatex
\begin{document}
yada yada\savepos{eek}\par
yada yada
\end{document}
```

Result: No error, but "eek" is printed, and there is nothing in the `aux` file. Alternatively, using `pdfsavepos{eek}` produces an error. Using TeXlive 2017, up to date.

EDIT2: The accepted answer is very informative. I was able to solve the problem for which I originally asked the question, and posted the solution as a follow-up answer, below.

Comment: Read [Hans Hagen, “LuaTEX 0.90 backend changes for PDF
and more”, TUGboat 37:1 53-57 (2016)](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-1/tb115hagen-pdf.pdf)

Comment: @HenriMenke Downloaded the article, will look. But of course, mere sniveling users, such as myself, do not expect to read that kind of thing. All we want is an example of usage. As this linked page says, "TeX was not designed as a programming language...". So do not be surprised if users are not programmers. http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-repeat-num.html

Comment: @RobtAll Good idea to have different names. You don't necessarily have to reimplement `\savepos`; I edited the suggestion at the top of the answer to a different approach.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, now that I understand what is going on, I have made progress. What I want to do can be done directly using the luatex `\savepos` command, without loading another package. When I get it working, I'll add an answer showing the code, in case anyone else finds it useful.

Comment: **Several years later**: Note that the package has been updated, simply use `\SavePos`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Your immediate problem

Unfortunately the `gridset` package defines a `\savepos` macro which has the same name as a LuaTeX primitive. If you don't need the LuaTeX `\savepos` functionality (at least under that exact name), you can do:

```
\let\luatexPrimitiveSavepos=\savepos
\let\savepos=\relax
\usapackage{gridset}
\let\gridsetPackageSavepos=\savepos
```

similar to what you mentioned in the question, and then use either `\luatexPrimitiveSavepos` or `\gridsetPackageSavepos`, whichever you need, avoiding the ambiguous name `\savepos`.

Maybe the package could be changed to do something reasonable under LuaTeX automatically, or (if feasible) just use a different name instead of `\savepos`.

---

### The “why”, as asked

In the LuaTeX engine, `\savepos` is a primitive. When TeX is asked to `\show` a primitive, it shows it as itself (for example, `\show\def` will show `\def=\def`).

This primitive is also present in the pdfTeX and XeTeX engines, under the name `\pdfsavepos`, but in the LuaTeX program they removed the `pdf` prefix. This is documented in the [LuaTeX manual, section 2.1.4 Changes from pdfTeX 1.40](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf#page=33):

> Because position tracking is also available in dvi mode the `\savepos`, `\lastxpos` and `\lastypos` commands now replace their `pdf` prefixed originals.

Also ([section 2.2 The backend primitives \pdf *](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf#page=39)):

> If you also want some backward compatibility, you can add:
> ...
> `\let\pdfsavepos \savepos`

(There are a bunch of such renamed primitives.)

---

### What is `\savepos` (or `\pdfsavepos`)

Some notes on this primitive `\savepos` (in LuaTeX) or `\pdfsavepos` (in pdfTeX and XeTeX). It originates with pdfTeX, and is best documented in [the pdfTeX manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf):

> ▶ `\pdflastxpos` (read–only integer)
> This primitive returns an integer number representing the absolute x coordinate of the last point marked by `\pdfsavepos`. The unit is ‘scaled points’ (sp).
> ▶ `\pdflastypos` (read–only integer)
> Completely analogous to `\pdflastxpos`, returning the y coordinate.
> ...
> ▶ \pdfsavepos (h, v, m)
> This primitive marks the current absolute (x, y) position on the media, with the reference point in the lower left corner. It is active only during page shipout, when the page is finally assembled. The position coordinates can then be retrieved by the `\pdflastxpos` and `\pdflastypos` primitives, and e.g. written out to some auxiliary file. The coordinates can be used only after the current `\shipout` has been finalized, therefore normally two pdfTeX runs are required to utilize these primitives. Starting with pdfTeX 1.40.0, this mechanism can be used also while running in DVI mode.

(As pointed out by @MarcelKrüger in a comment, the `(h, v, m)` indicates that this primitive can be used in any of the modes: horizontal mode / vertical mode / math mode.)

(As these primitives comes from pdfTeX, its extensions XeTeX and LuaTeX don't document them very extensively, the same way they don't document TeX primitives: in the [XeTeX manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xetex/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf#page=18) the explanation is brief, and entirely omitted in the LuaTeX manual.)

You can use them as follows:

```
% compile with pdflatex or xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pdfpageheight=2.5in % Really short pages, just so that I can get a screenshot.

yada yada\pdfsavepos eek\par
yada yada

\newpage

The last saved position was x=\the\pdflastxpos, and y=\the\pdflastypos.
\end{document}
```

or

```
% compile with lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pageheight=2.5in % Really short pages, just so that I can get a screenshot.

yada yada\savepos eek\par
yada yada

\newpage

The last saved position was x=\the\lastxpos, and y=\the\lastypos.
\end{document}
```

Both of which produce:

[image: output]

(Here, when compiling with `lualatex` and `xelatex` the “x” number is slightly different compared to compiling with `pdflatex`: the reason as @HenriMenke points out is that these two load Latin Modern by default, instead of `pdflatex` which loads `cmr` (Computer Modern) by default—and these fonts have slightly different metrics.)

See also the article [pdfTeX’s little secret: Tracking positions](https://www.ntg.nl/maps/25/10.pdf) by Hans Hagen in [MAPS 25 (2000)](https://www.ntg.nl/maps/25/) pp. 74–78, which seems to be about these primitives.

This primitive (whether called `\pdfsavepos` or `\savepos`) is of course entirely unrelated to the `\savepos` macro defined by the `gridset` package. The package has unfortunately chosen a name that is used for a primitive by a newer engine.

Comment: Really? See my edit to the original question.

Comment: @RobtAll Yes really. :-) `\pdfsavepos` gives an error because it's not defined by default in LuaTeX. And it's not surprising that with `\savepos` you get "eek" in the output and nothing in the aux file; after all this is the same behaviour if you have `\pdfsavepos` and compile with pdflatex.

Comment: Maybe that's what it does, but it makes no sense at all. If `\savepos` is a lualatex primitive, then it ought to DO something. Instead, it exhibits no behavior that I can discern. So, how is it used?

Comment: Further: I should note that "read the manual" is not adequate. Nobody reads a manual to find how to use a command that is mentioned numerous times in search results - but doesn't work that way any longer!

Comment: @RobtAll Added to answer.

Comment: Regarding `(h, v, m)`: It stands for the TeX modes in which the primitive can be used. `\(pdf)savepos` is usable in horizontal, vertical and math mode.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Ah that explains it, thanks! I guessed `h, v` might stand for “horizontal” and “vertical”, but didn't connect it to TeX modes so didn't figure out what the “m” might have been :-) Added it to the answer.

Comment: You get slightly different numbers because the LuaLaTeX format loads Latin Modern instead of `cmr` by default and the metrics are slightly different.

Comment: Ah, now you're talking! Needless to say, most Internet search results for `\savepos` return the gridset package, or another one with similar purpose. It's not at all clear that luatex is doing its own thing, under the same name. As for `\pdfsavepos`, that happens to be defined as `\savepos` via other LuaLaTeX compatibility packages that I load (in my real document, not the MWE).

Comment: It looks like `zref-savepos` (oberdeik) might also have a problem in luatex (but I am not certain). The *.sty file does say that it is for pdftex and xetex, but I have come across at least one package (not by Oberdeik) that failed to mention luatex, simply because the package was older than that.

Comment: I put the answer to good use. See my lengthy code, posted as an additional answer.

Comment: @RobtAll Nice, glad to see.

Comment: NB: This fix will still clash with other packages that rely on `\savepos`, such as `tikz`. See this answer for more details and a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450845/151897

Comment: @Alec Yes that's correct. As I said in the second sentence the proposed fix in the first section of the answer only applies “if you don't need the LuaTeX \savepos functionality”, though I know it can be hard to know whether some package you use needs it. Anyway, the main point of this answer was to answer the “why” (which was the focus of the question initially); the fix was only an afterthought. I've upvoted your question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

I asked my question with a particular application in mind. For the benefit of anyone, I will now show you what I did. Similar code will appear in the next update of my custom document class (novel), but the following code will work in any document class using LuaLaTeX.

Nature of the problem: I write only fiction for print to paper. That means continuous text, not equations. From time to time, there is a scene break within a chapter. The scene break is denoted by a blank line.

However, good typographic practice forbids placing the blank line at the very top or bottom of a page, where it might not be noticed. Also, placing it with only one line above or below looks bad.

So, the following code detects the page position of my `\scenebreak` command. If it is badly placed, a Warning is issued.

To see it in operation, load the code into an editor (such as TeXworks) that displays Warnings. Vary the number of `\yadayada` from 43 to 48. At 43 and 48, no problem. At 44 and 47, you will be warned that `\scenebreak` is too close to page top/bottom. At 45 and 46, you will be warned that `\scenebreak` is at top/bottom.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
% Compile with LuaLaTeX.
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\flushbottom
%
\makeatletter
% Assumes contast \baselineskip.
\def\@LinesPerPage{46} % Main text. Change to actual value for your document.
%
\newlength\TotalYpos
\def\InitialYpos{% top of text block
  \begingroup%
    \savepos%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \protect\@TotalYpos{\noexpand\number\lastypos}%
    }%
  \endgroup%
}
%
\def\@TotalYpos#1{\setlength\TotalYpos{#1sp}}
%
\newcommand\scenebreak{%
  \leavevmode\getBreakpos{scenebreak}~\par
}
\newlength\CurrentBreakpos
\def\getBreakpos#1{%
  \begingroup%
    \savepos%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \protect\@getBreakpos{\noexpand\number\lastypos}{\thepage}{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup%
}
\gdef\@getBreakpos#1#2#3{} % nothing, when reading aux at beginning
\AtBeginDocument{
  \gdef\@getBreakpos#1#2#3{% numerical position sp, page, break type
    \setlength\CurrentBreakpos{#1sp}% measured up from very bottom of page.
    \FPsub{\@BreakLines}{\strip@pt\TotalYpos}{\strip@pt\CurrentBreakpos}
    \FPdiv{\@BreakLines}{\@BreakLines}{\strip@pt\baselineskip}%
    \FPround{\@BreakLines}{\@BreakLines}{0}% integer lines from text top
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{scenebreak}}{%
      \xdef\thisline{\@BreakLines}%
      \ifnum\@BreakLines=1%
        \ClassWarning{any}{Replace \string\scenebreak\space at top of ^^J%
         page #2 with alternative.}%
      \fi%
      \ifnum\@BreakLines=\@LinesPerPage%
        \ClassWarning{any}{Replace \string\scenebreak\space at bottom of ^^J%
         page #2 with alternative.}%
      \fi%
    }{}%
    \FPsub{\@nearthebottom}{\@LinesPerPage}{1}%
    \ifnum\@BreakLines=2%
      \ClassWarning{any}{\string\ #3 too close to top of page #2.}%
    \fi%
    \ifnum\@BreakLines=\@nearthebottom%
      \ClassWarning{any}{\string\ #3 too close to bottom of page #2.}%
    \fi%
  }%
} % end \AtBeginDocument
\makeatother
%
% This is for the MWE, not part of the position code:
\newcount\yadacurrentcount
\newcount\yadaendcount
\newcommand\yadayada[1]{%
  \yadacurrentcount=1%
  \yadaendcount=#1%
  \loop%
    \makebox[\parindent][l]{\the\yadacurrentcount.}%
    Yada yada.\par
    \advance\yadacurrentcount 1%
  \ifnum\yadacurrentcount<\yadaendcount%
  \repeat%
}
%
\begin{document}
\InitialYpos%
\yadayada{43} % vary from 43 to 48 to see effect
\scenebreak
\yadayada{30}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the show, but here is one additional solution:

Markus Kohm, author of the `gridset` package has an updated version, dated 2017, on his own website: https://komascript.de/gridset. This version correctly deals with LuaTeX.

However, that site contains two disclaimers:

> Note: I do not longer recommend to use this package!
>
> Note: You cannot find the current release on CTAN.

So, YMMV.