Is it possible to record the exact location of a box in latex after generating a pdf?
In my latex quiz code, I can generate boxes for users to write like this:
\ans{3cm}

The problem is, depending on the surrounding text, the exact location of the box will shift.
Is there a way to ask latex to record the bounding box: (x,y,w,h) as it is rendered in the document?  For example, I would like to output a textfile like this:
Q1    72,72, 36, 18

Any units (such as points) would be fine.

use \pdfsavepos at the start of the box, which will save the reference point, and you presumably know the size of the box, so you know the top right cordinate as well.

Using my answer to your other question, you can also do this without an additional package using the new properties label/ref framework of the kernel.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\fboxsep=0pt
\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{questioncount}%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 points)}\quad
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ans {  m }
{% tikz is surely overkill
  \fbox{\makebox(#1,0.75cm){}}%
}


\newenvironment{quiz}[2]{%
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo.png}\hfill
  \textbf{#1 #2} \hfill
  Name: \ans{6cm} \hfill NetID: \ans{4cm} \hfill Section \ans{1cm}%
  \vspace{0.5cm}%
  \par
  \hrule
}{}

\begin{document}
\quiz{course}{title}
\q{30} instructions
\begin{itemize}
  \item What voltage is nominal (ideal) for 74LS parts? \pdfsavepos\ans{2 cm}\,V
\end{itemize}
\RecordProperties{volts}{xpos,ypos}%
Last time, the box was at (\RefProperty{volts}{xpos},\RefProperty{volts}{ypos}).

\pdfsavepos
\RecordProperties{new}{xpos,ypos}%
Last time, the point just marked was at (\RefProperty{new}{xpos},\RefProperty{new}{ypos}).
\end{document}

As with the linked zref-based approach, the position is always one compilation out-of-date, so the document needs to be stable before the result can be trusted.


I didn't know about \pdfsavepos and \RecordProperties, thank you. Note I saw in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427533/savepos-savepos-in-lualatex-why that if the compilation is in lualatex you must replace \pdfsavepos by \savepos.

@pascal974 Yes. You need to pick the right macro for the engine you're using. There is \tex_savepos:D in expl3, but D means Do not use unless you are part of the kernel team ;).Although that is actually from the example given in the documentation, so the advice doesn't seem entirely consistent for this particular point. They need to make some OK-to-use thing available ;).
