# How can (La)TeX read UTF-8?

Tags: unicode

As described in *The TeXbook*, TeX reads files byte by byte, regardless of the particular format -- as I understand, this is just how IniTeX is set up.

I also understand that LaTeX is just a collection of macros built on top of IniTeX, described in most distributions of TeX by the file `latex.ltx`.

The above two things are at odds with my understanding of LaTeX's ability to read UTF-8. I was under the impression that reading the input byte by byte (and thus for instance, only being able to access numbers from 0 to 255 using `\char` or something) was baked into TeX, and thus would exist in all variants built on top of it.

Thus, how is LaTeX able to do this?

Comment: The TeXbook describes the so-called Knuth-TeX engine, as well as a collection of macros frequently called "PlainTeX". Are you aware of newer engines called pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX?

Comment: You could be asking one of (at least) two questions here. Are you wondering how _e.g._ XeTeX (natively UTF-8) can be derived from Knuth's TeX (8-bit). Or are you wondering how 8-bit TeX engines deal with UTF-8 input (conversion of 'raw' bytes to codpoints to output)?

Comment: @JosephWright The former.

Comment: @Mico I am aware they exist. Are you saying that the newer TeX engines read input utf8 char by utf8 char? How would this work? I feel like a lot of things would break -- as Knuth describes, catcodes, mathcodes, and delcodes are only defined for 256 distinct values (all the possible bytes), no?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222286/what-are-the-incompatibilities-of-pdftex-xetex-and-luatex. There, I look in detail at the differences between engines, some of which are linked to Unicode support. (The questions are distinct, it's not a duplicate.)

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to know how the 8-bit engines handle utf8 input you can use \tracingmacros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\tracingmacros =1 ä }
\end{document}
```

which gives

```
Ã->\UTFviii@two@octets Ã

\UTFviii@two@octets #1#2->\expandafter \UTFviii@defined \csname u8:#1\string #2
\endcsname 
#1<-Ã
#2<-¤

\UTFviii@defined #1->\ifx #1\relax \if \relax \expandafter \UTFviii@checkseq \s
tring #1\relax \relax \UTFviii@undefined@err {#1}\else \PackageError {inputenc}
{Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence}\UTFviii@invalid@help \fi \else \expandafter #1\fi

#1<-\u8:Ã¤ 

\u8:Ã¤ ->\IeC {\"a}
```

That means the the first byte of the `ä` (the `Ã`) is an active char, a command which then picks up the next byte and then calls `\u8:Ã¤` which calls `\"a`. In this way (pdf)latex can handle quite a lot of utf8 input but it has e.g. problems with "char + combining accent" as there is no sensible code for the combining accent to go back to add an accent on the char.

Comment: Just a comment to point out log file containing the trace got viewed by editor in some 8bit encoding, presumably iso-latin-1 (like Emacs does for me), not in UTF8... so `Ã` is only one byte. This is tacit in your answer...

Answer (score 5):

In order to move from 8-bit TeX90 to Unicode XeTeX or LuaTeX, there is work to do in extending/modifying internal structures. However, that is largely a question of effort rather than any major conceptual limitation. Knuth after all extended TeX from 7-bit to 8-bit between TeX82 (TeX 2) and TeX90 (TeX 3).

Both XeTeX and LuaTeX read files in UTF-8 rather than on a per-byte basis. This happens well before any TeX-related processes are involved, and as such at the macro level there are only UTF-8 characters. (One can alter this in LuaTeX: see [`luainputenc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luainputenc) for example.) Both engines then use tables which are extended to cover the full Unicode range.

The change in accepted input can be used to test for Unicode-aware engines, as shown in an example from https://www.contextgarden.net/Encodings_and_Regimes

```
\def\test#1#2!{\def\secondarg{#2}}
\test χ!\relax % That's Chi, a 2-byte utf-8 sequence
\ifx\secondarg\empty \message{newstuff}\else \message{tex82}\fi
```

In the main, macro code does not need altering to accept Unicode: the engines deal with the byte aspect, so from a macro viewpoint everything is 'as expected'. Of course, there is a little set up to do, for example setting `\catcode`, `\uccode`, *etc.* for the full Unicode range. Today, this is handled by using the [`unicode-data`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-data), so is built-in to both plain TeX-derived and LaTeX formats.

There are a few places that LaTeX has to be aware of which engine is in use, but the direct impact of Unicode is largley limited to

- Setting up the data for `\catcode`, *etc.*
- Setting up hyphenation patterns (which today are all stored as UTF-8 and
  require more work to use with pdfTeX than with Unicode TeX engines)
- (Not) setting up support for Unicode support based on active 8-bit characters
  (See [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471104) for details
  of how that works in 8-bit engines)

Other aspects at the macro layer are related to other functionality, for example the ability of both XeTeX and LuaTeX to load system fonts: that requires a Unicode
font encoding (`TU`), but that is distinct from handling input.