# Unexpected difference between lualatex and pdflatex with babel and quotes

Tags: luatex, babel

Consider this tex:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
\begin{document}

Aldred, Rachel. 2010. {`{``On the Outside''}: Constructing Cycling
Citizenship.'} \emph{Social \& Cultural Geography} 11 (1): 35--52.

\end{document}
```

Compiling with pdflatex, we get

‘“On the Outside”: Constructing Cycling Citizenship.’

But with lualatex, we get

“‘On the Outside”: Constructing Cycling Citizenship.’

The difference here is the treatment of ``` `{`` ``` at the start.  pdflatex reads it as singlequote doublequote, while lualatex reads it as doublequote singlequote.

What explains this difference?  Is it expected?  Is it a bug in lualatex, or undefined behavior?

(Originally reported at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6958)

Comment: Looks like lualatex is behaving incorrectly. As an aside, I've always used `\,` to separate adjacent single and double quotes.

Comment: It is expected, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222286/ and especially the point about ligature prevention and braces

Comment: Thanks @cgnieder, I guess that answers the question!